# Delete a substring from a string with a filename in Perl

Tags: perl

This is a `makefile` output, and I need to delete the `*.d` and `*.o` files from it. How would I do it?

```
gcc -c -m64 -march=x86-64  -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I. -I../include -I -MD -MF out/target/mytree/mycode/build/linux.x86_64/expr.d -o out/target/mytree/mycode/build/linux.x86_64/obj/expr.o expr.cpp
```

I don't want to split the line with `whitespaces`, do my search, and then use join maybe to put the string back.

Can I do it any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $src_file, "<", "test.txt") or die $!;
open(my $dst_file, ">", "dest.txt") or die $!;
while (<$src_file>) { 
    my $line = $_; 
    $line =~ s/\s+\S+\.[do]\s/ /g;
    print $dst_file $line;
}
close($src_file);
close($dst_file);
```

It will transform:

```
gcc -c -m64 -march=x86-64  -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I. -I../include -I -MD -MF out/target/mytree/mycode/build/linux.x86_64/expr.d -o out/target/mytree/mycode/build/linux.x86_64/obj/expr.o expr.cpp
to
gcc -c -m64 -march=x86-64  -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I. -I../include -I -MD -MF  -o  expr.cpp
```

Or you can use this regexp instead:

```
$line =~ s/-(?:MF|o)\s+\S+\.[do]\s/ /g;
```

to also remove the trailing `-MF` and `-o`, to transform to:

```
gcc -c -m64 -march=x86-64  -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I. -I../include -I -MD   expr.cpp
```

Comment: Pleasure. Feel free to vote up for this answer if you like :)

Comment: I would love to, but I can't :(
I just joined in.

Comment: While your solution may work, it is a long way from being best-practice Perl. Please `use strict` and `use warnings` on every Perl program, and use lexical file handles, and the three-parameter form of `open`. Also, `(d|o)` should really be the non-capturing `(?:d|o)` or ideally just the character class `[do]`.

Comment: Except for by far the most important feature: `use strict`, `use warnings` :)

Comment: Oops, forgot it... now added!

Comment: `[d|o]` is wrong. That matches any of `d`, `|`, or `o`. Should be just `[do]`. +1 anyway